# Access static property from type

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class Action {
    public static DEPENDENCIES: (typeof Action)[] = [];

    public static MIN_USES: number | null = null;
    public static MAX_USES: number | null = null;
}

class SomeAction extends Action {
    public static DEPENDENCIES = [SomeOtherAction];

    public statuc MIN_USES = null;
    public static MAX_USES = 1;
}

class SomeOtherAction extends Action {
    public static DEPENDENCIES = [];

    public static MIN_USES = 1;
    public static MAX_USES = 1;
}
```

Now, I can access a static property like this:

```
class Turn {
    public can(A: typeof Action) {
        console.log(A.MIN_USES);
    }
}

turn.can(SomeOtherAction); // console.log(1);
```

But now I want SomeOtherAction to have a constructor with 2 parameters.
This causes the following error:

```
Class static side 'typeof SomeOtherAction' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Action'.
```

This happens because the constructor signatures are not the same.
This is fixed by replacing `(typeof Action)[]` with `(new(...args: any[]) => Action)[]`.

But now I can't access the static properties anymore:

```
Property 'MIN_USES' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => Action'.
```

Is there anyway to both be able to access the static properties AND have different constructor signatures?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your usage of the `typeof` operator. The `typeof` constraints that the structure of the classes are exactly equal. This includes the `new` property, which is commonly known as constructor.

I fixed it as follows:

```
type ActionType = (Omit<typeof Action, 'new'>)

class Action {
    public static DEPENDENCIES: ActionType[] = [];

    public static MIN_USES: number | null = null;
    public static MAX_USES: number | null = null;
}

class SomeOtherAction extends Action {
    public static DEPENDENCIES = [];

    public static MIN_USES = 1;
    public static MAX_USES = 1;

    constructor(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
        super()   
    }
}

class SomeAction extends Action {
    public static DEPENDENCIES = [SomeOtherAction];

    public static MIN_USES = null;
    public static MAX_USES = 1;
}

class Turn {
    public can(a: ActionType) {
        console.log(a.MIN_USES);
    }
}

const turn = new Turn()
turn.can(SomeOtherAction); // console.log(1);
```

The `ActionType` represents the signature of `Action` without the constructor. Therefore, the constructor constraint is omitted.

After creating the type, I replaced all `typeof Action` notations by `ActionType`

Comment: It does fix the error, thanks! However, somewhere else in my code I do `action instanceof A` where A is a type of Action. This now throws an error because of the removal of `new`.

Comment: If I could help, it would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted :)